# How to retrieve the selected values from dual listbox with aspnet core c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, listbox, selected

I have incorporated the Bootstrap Dual Listbox, in my aspnet core web site, but I don´t know how to retrieve the selected values in the right listbox (multiples values).

In my web site I have a language dropbox, and a dual listbox, that are loaded with diferent quests each time I change a language.

My ViewModel.cs

```
public class QuestViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> QuestIds { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Quests { set; get; }
}
```

My cshtml

```
 <form asp-action="add" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Language</label>
        <select asp-for="Language" class="form-control m-b" id="idLanguage">
            <option value="PT">PT</option>
            <option value="FR">FR</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
            <option value="ES">ES</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <select asp-for="QuestIds" asp-items="@Model.Quests" class="form-control dual_select" multiple="multiple" name="duallistbox_quest">
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

My javascript with ajax, calling my apicontroller to fill again the dual listbox

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[name=duallistbox_quest]').bootstrapDualListbox({
        selectorMinimalHeight: 200
    });

    $("#idLanguage").on("change", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Quest/GetAllQuests",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { Id: $("#idLanguage").val() }, //id of the language
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
                $('[name=duallistbox_quest]').empty();
                $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                    $('[name=duallistbox_quest]').append($('<option value="' + item["value"] + '"> ' + item["text"] + ' </option>'));
                });
                $('[name=duallistbox_quest]').bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error oops.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My Post

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> add(QuestViewModel model)
{
    return View();//just to test 
}
```

Here in my post the viewmodel have model.QuestIds always null.

What is missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Jolynice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

I need to change the name of dual listbox by the viewmodel property, like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select asp-for="QuestIds" asp-items="@Model.Quests" class="form-control dual_select" multiple="multiple" name="QuestIds">
    </select>
</div>
```

Then don´t forget to update the javascript script.